# Installed MVVMLight - doing WP7 - VS2010 works fine; Blend 4 doesn't

Tags: mvvm-light

I can create an MVVMLight phone app in VS2010.  It runs as it should.  I can open it in Blend 4.  That's all fine.

When I create a new WP7 MVVM project in Blend, several things are wrong:
1.  Just compiling, get "A start page has not been specified...."  WMAppManifest.xml has incomplete Task section.  NavigationPage attrib. with MainPage.xaml is not there.
2.  When I manually fix that and build, I get "Project could not be built."  It references Microsoft.Phone.Controls.dll and Microsoft.Phone.Control.Navigation (no .dll--and not found, of course).

A non-MVVM Blend phone project correctly references Microsoft.Phone.dll (and Microsoft.Phone.Interop.dll).  And it works fine.

Where have I gone wrong in my MVVM installation for Blend 4?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the newest version of Blend 4 for Windows Phone 7 does not support custom template. What you see now in Blend are the old project templates.

I am aware that the install process at the moment is terrible, and I am working with members of the community to solve that issue (including cleaning up old files).

In the mean time, if you want to clean up old files, there is a list at http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvm/cleaning. Again, sorry that the process is manual at this time.

Cheers,
Laurent

Comment: Laurent, I don't quite understand.  Are you saying I can make things work correctly by removing some things?  The .../cleaning page is too comprehensive for me to be able to decipher.  Or should I just continue to start in VS and then move to Blend 4?